# How can i use obf file in my android app

Tags: android, osmdroid

I am developing an android app that use osmdroid open source library. I create offline map with http://extract.bbbike.org/ website. This site creat obf file. My question is how can i use obf file to show offline map in my app.

Comment: I don't thinck you can what makes you think it's possible.  .obf is osmAnd specific.

Comment: Create your map with MOBAC.